# I'm having problems with 3D movement according to 2 angles

Tags: python, math, 3d, raytracing

I'm making a ray tracer and the ray movement according to the angles is wrong.

I made a function that sets the ray velocity in 3D space to avoid calculating them when not necessary.

I have the X and Y angle and I want to convert them to velocity in 3 axes, but they are not moving correctly.

'Xa' and 'Ya' are the yaw and pitch angles. The ray will move by the 'vel' variable (X,Y,Z).

```py
def updateVel(Xa,Ya):
    global vel
    vel[0] = math.cos(math.radians(Xa)) * math.sin(math.radians(Ya))
    vel[1] = math.cos(math.radians(Xa)) * math.cos(math.radians(Ya))
    vel[2] = -math.sin(math.radians(Xa))
```

Comment: `but it's all wrong` how? This is not a [mre]. This is 116 lines of code, of which most of it is certainly unnecessary to be able to demonstrate your problem. Plus, you've given zero explanation. You haven't done any work to help us understand your issue, so why should we be expected to do a hugely disproportionate amount of work to help you?

Comment: I'm sorry. Yes, I did take your help for granted. I have edited the question explaining more.

Comment: This appears to not be an issue with understanding the code, but the math. Maybe ask this on a math-focused StackExchange site?

Comment: Or, since it's graphics related, https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/ or possibly https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Comment: The formula with which you calculate the vector from the angles is correct. Of course, the function should not set a global variable but `return` the one value, but this need not necessarily be the problem. The problem is either that the angles are wrong or you are using the vector wrong.

Comment: Thank you. I think I need to find an equation for rotating the angles correctly instead.